# Can regular sugar be substituted for maple sugar?

Tags: substitutions, sugar

I found a [cake recipe](http://fragrantvanillacake.blogspot.com/2010/11/pomegranate-vanilla-cake.html) that wants maple sugar in it, but I don't have maple sugar.  Can regular sugar be substituted?

Comment: Can rice wine be substituted with grape wine?

Answer (score 8):

If maple is intended to be a significant flavor in the cake (i.e. you're making a maple cake, or a maple rum cake) it's not going to be the same without it. The best substitutions would be maple syrup, or white sugar plus maple extract, so that you still get that wonderful flavor.

As for quantities, looking around online, the common recommendations for replacing 1/2 cup of maple sugar seem to be:

- 3/4 cup white sugar and 1 teaspoon maple extract; or
- 1 cup maple syrup, and reducing other liquid in the recipe by 1/4 cup.

If you can do without the maple flavor, then you could just use the 3/4 cup white sugar, but I suspect it wasn't a superfluous ingredient!

In the case of this recipe, it looks like the maple is important, but there aren't liquids to reduce. That probably means that the easiest option is the maple extract, but you could also take the recommended amount of maple syrup, and boil it down until you've lost the right amount of water. (For example, for 1 cup of maple sugar, take 2 cups maple syrup and reduce it to 1.5 cups.)

Comment: I agree its very unlikely to be superfluous, maple sugar is *much* more expensive than refined cane or beat sugar. And it has a strong flavor.

Comment: The cake is a pomegranate vanilla cake.  The other liquids in the cake are coconut oil and pomegranate juice.

Comment: @AtlasRN Well, if it's [this one](http://fragrantvanillacake.blogspot.com/2010/11/pomegranate-vanilla-cake.html), sure looks like it's a pomegranate maple vanilla cake; a cup of maple sugar has some serious flavor.

Comment: That's the one.  But I didn't really want to go buy maple sugar.  I already have maple syrup.  But I also feel that the other liquids are necessary and don't want to reduce those.

Comment: @AtlasRN You can't replace the coconut fat (which is solid at room temperatures, I don't know why they call it "oil"), fats in a cake have a different role than the liquids. You could consider using grenadine instead of the pomegranate juice (it is more concentrated), but I don't know the exact substitution amount.

Comment: @AtlasRN I edited the probable best methods into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient post, but you got some terrible advice.  Adding for the next person google sends here:

Maple sugar is mostly sucrose, same as white sugar.  Substitute 1 to 1 or your sweetness will be off.

Maple syrup is maple sugar + water.  The Water is 1/3 by weight, so if substituting adjust your proportions and liquids accordingly.